# In vim python-mode, how can I get pep8-naming to work?

Tags: vim, pep8, python-mode, flake8

I've installed pep8 naming (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8-naming)

```
finchpowers@dev:~$ flake8 --version
2.1.0 (pep8: 1.5.7, pyflakes: 0.8.1, mccabe: 0.2.1, naming: 0.2.2) CPython 2.7.3 on Linux
```

So it looks fine. In my .vimrc I have

```
let g:pymode_lint_checkers = "pyflakes,pep8,mccabe,pep257"
```

When in vim, none of my naming errors are reported. Is it supported? Have I missed any step?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the pathogen plugin manager for vim and loading flake8 into syntastic.

This worked for me:
~/.vimrc:

```
call pathogen#infect()
syntax enable
let g:syntastic_python_checkers=['flake8']
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question, he wants to know how to get it to work in pymode's lint.

Comment: It's true that it doesn't answers the question as such, but it is a working solution to get the functionality I want: naming errors.